# Wait for the Next Input and Store it (Unity/C#)

Tags: c#, input, unity-game-engine

me again :D
I got the next problem, but this time it looks like i am not able to solve it, and it also shouldnt be grammar problems^^

Well, right now im trying to make a Inputclass for UNity3D (in C#) for our Classproject. I got the Input itself to work, and everything is fine. But the reason i had to do it, making controlls changeable at runtime, still is a problem. I tried different ways to save the Keys (textfield and writing the keycodes -> our game designer disliked it). right now i tried to do it with Coroutines and my last try was to transfer it to another function and start all the code after the mouse has been released and no Input should be done. Anyways it dsent work. THis is the Code that should do the magic:

```
    void PassKey(string wantedKey)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) == false)
    {
        Event uInput = Event.current;
        wantedKey = uInput.character.ToString();
        Debug.Log (wantedKey + uInput.character);
    }
}
```

this gets called in here:

```
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0,qScreenWidthX / 2, qScreenHeightX / 5), rightText))
    {

        PassKey(right);
    }
```

(this button exists for every Key).

Do you guys have any idea how to wait for the next input AFTER the mouse has been released?

I dont need concrete code, but maybe a hint how i could get this working.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  If all you want is to trigger something on mouse up, use `Input.GetButtonUp ("Fire1")`.  The only way to get values after mouse release is to wait for the next Input frame during your next Update(), it's not like reading `Input.GetButtonUp ("Fire1")` removes that from key event.

Comment: well, we had to rewrite th Input class for our Project. (Leader/Game Designer wants the controls changeable at runtime). THen i gave him a sollution, but you had to write down the keycode to have they saved. now im trying to get it working that you click on a button and the next input that is done (no matter what) is going to be saved.

Comment: As for your situation, it seems like you'll have to sit at a table with your design partner, and take some time to draw out what he wants. Take a pencil and paper, draw out and write down everything. I get the feeling he wants something and you don't know or understand it.

Comment: As for your question, regardless if beneath answers are correct or the things you have tried: keep in mind that `Input.GetButton` and `Input.GetButtonDown`/`Input.GetButtonUp` are two different things! But your usage of `GetButtonUp` is the correct one in this case, but I just wanted to let you keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

if I got your question true, you need to track the very next key pressed after mouse released, this is not very hard to solve, just after any mouse releasing (in mouse release delegate) set a boolean value (x) to true, and for other events delegates (any event that causes cancellation of the process) set the value(x) to false, not in your key press you would identify that is mouse released before it or not, simple:

```
void mouseReleased(){// event when your mouse get released
   this.x=true;
}

void anyOtherEvent(){// for any other event that cancel the process, like wheel
   this.x=false;
}

void keyPressed(){//
   if(this.x){
     //ddo your operation
   }
   this.x=false;
}
```

hope I got your question right.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your answer, but it didnt help. But i think i get now what the mistake actually is. The Event uInput dosent wait for any keypresses, it just makes uInput being empty and then passes this.
So i think i need somehthing that makes uINput actually wait for Input.

Comment: you also can after mouse release event add the key event to the desired object, and after key event remove it again, this ensures you that unless a mouse release event event, there is no any key event here

Comment: still dosent wait for the Input. It saves "None" to the Variable, so i think i need a way to make Event Wait for Input. Maybe stop all Code until a Key has pressed?
Also i cant realy wrap this all into a If-block, as it will simply skip this part if no Key (or what ever) is pressed and it wont even get near the Eventpart of the function.

Comment: Wow, what do you mean pause all codes? it's will be disaster, why doesn't work? you also can after first event (mouse click, anything), add a global event listener(add event to a container, something that fetch every events) for getting the second event (key press, anything), if you still have problem, send an image of your form please

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's clarifying comments above, here is a snippet that should work for simple keys like 'a','b','c', etc.

The easiest way to capture the keystroke is to use a simple flag to store when the mouse has been clicked, or whatever method you want to use to indicate that the next key is to be reassigned.  In the example below, when left mouse is clicked, the code will watch for [Input.inputString](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html) to be anything but empty.  When `Input.inputString` contains anything, `ReassignKey()` will use the first key stroke as the key assignment you want to use.

Keep in mind that `inputString` could contain multiple keyStrokes if there is a large delay between frames.  That's why I'm only using the first character.

```
public class KeyCapture : MonoBehaviour {
bool captureKey = false;
string assignedKey = "a";

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    ReassignKey();

    // Mouse-click = wait for next key press
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
        captureKey = true;
        Debug.Log("Waiting for next keystroke");
    }

    // Display message for currently assigned control.
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(assignedKey)){
        Debug.Log("Action mapped to key: " + assignedKey);
    }
}

void ReassignKey(){
    if(!captureKey)return;

    // ignore frames without keys
    if(Input.inputString.Length <= 0)return;

    // Input.inputString stores all keys pressed
    // since last frame but I only want to use a single
    // character.
    string originalKey = assignedKey;
    assignedKey = Input.inputString[0].ToString();
    captureKey = false;

    Debug.Log("Reassigned key '" + originalKey + "' to key '" + assignedKey + "'");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thy @Jerdak and @user 2511414. I got the problems solution :D  It was a bit like an epiphany this morning, the needed Code to return the Key that was hit is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < e; i++)
    {
        if(Input.GetKey((KeyCode)i))
        {
        return (KeyCode)i;
        }
            {
```

Im iterating through KeyCodes and check if any Key is pressed, and then Return the key that was actually pressed.
THe problem with the other solutions was that my Lead hates multiple, avoidable If-parts.